# Cross compiling Mono framework 3.0.6+ for MIPS

Tags: mono, mips, cross-compiling

I am trying to cross-compile Mono framework (3.0.6) for MIPS platform. There are few issues I have found so I would like to ask the community whether there are known or not.

**My environment**: Linux 3.2.0-39-generic #62-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 28 00:28:53 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**Toolchain**: Sourcery G++ Lite 4.3-51

**command-line**:

> ./configure --prefix=/home/dev/mono-3.0.6-mips --host=mips-linux-gnu --enable-minimal=profiler,debug,logging,soft_debug --without-mcs-docs --target=mips-linux-gnu --with-moonlight=no --with-tls=pthread --with-sigaltstack=no --with-profile4_5=yes CXXFLAGS="-mips32r2 -march=24kf -mtune=24kf -EL" CFLAGS="-mips32r2 -march=24kf -mtune=24kf -EL" && make

**Issue #1**:
When I managed it to configure, compilation stopped with the following error:

> mini-gc.c:2551: error: redefinition of 'mini_gc_enable_gc_maps_for_aot'
>
> mini-gc.c:2518: error: previous definition of 'mini_gc_enable_gc_maps_for_aot' was here

**Issue #2**:
After I commented out the second declaration of **mini_gc_enable_gc_maps_for_aot** it compiled but looks like Sourcery G++ linker crashed:

> /home/dev/mips-4.3/bin/../lib/gcc/mips-linux-gnu/4.3.2/../../../../mips-linux-gnu/bin/ld: BFD (Sourcery G++ Lite 4.3-51) 2.18.50.20080215 assertion fail /scratch/clm/2008q3-lite/obj/binutils-src-4.3-51-mips-linux-gnu-i686-pc-linux-gnu/bfd/elfxx-mips.c:2651

Could anyone led some light to this problem? I failed to find any articles/info describing building Mono for MIPS architecture (at least some recent information). According to [this](http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/02/Mono-Android-MIPS) link, support for MIPS was added about a year ago. Mono itself should fully support MIPS since [3.0.4 version](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_3.0.6#MIPS_port).

Answer (score 5):

I am posting this info for everyone else who will struggle with the same problem (building Mono for MIPS platform):

At last I was able to build mono runtime for MIPS platform using the following command line:

> ./configure --prefix=/home/dev/mono-3.0.6-mips --host=mips-linux-gnu --enable-minimal=profiler,debug,logging,soft_debug --without-mcs-docs --target=mips-linux-gnu --with-moonlight=no --with-tls=pthread --with-sigaltstack=no --with-profile4_5=yes CXXFLAGS="-mips32r2 -EL" CFLAGS="-mips32r2 -EL" LDFLAGS=-EL CPPFLAGS="-mips32r2 -EL" ASFLAGS=-EL CC="mips-linux-gnu-gcc -EL"

Specifying -EL flag for all the tools fixed issue with mono linking using ld (see Issue #2 in my initial post).

The last issue left is to make the mono build system to build mscorlib.dll. Invoking different **make** commands inside mcs/class folder doesn`t do anything.